# Bound of Renyi divergence under addition of random variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Consider two random variables, $X$ with $p_X(x)$ and $Y$ with $p_Y(y)$. These random variables have Renyi divergence at level $\alpha$ of $R_1 = D_\alpha(p_X || p_Y)$

Now noise is added:

$X’ = X+A$

$Y’ = Y+B$

The question is: what is the lowest upper bound for $D_\alpha(p_{X’} || p_{Y’})$?

The divergences with the noise are upper bounded:
$D_\alpha(p_A || p_B) \leq R_2$,
$D_\alpha(p_B || p_A) \leq R_2$,
$D_\alpha(p_X || p_A) \leq R_2$,
$D_\alpha(p_A || p_X) \leq R_2$,
$D_\alpha(p_Y || p_B) \leq R_2$,
$D_\alpha(p_B || p_Y) \leq R_2$. It is assumed that $\alpha > 1$ and $R_1$, $R_2$ depend on $\alpha$.

Also we know the following: all distributions are unimodal, and the variance and mode of A and B differ by at most 10% (in other words $0.9 \leq var_A / var_B \leq 1.1$, and $-0.1 \leq (mode_A-mode_B) / mode_B \leq .1$)

Few attempts I already made:

$D_\alpha(p_X || p_Y) \geq D_\alpha(p_{X+A} || p_{Y+A})$ by Data Processing Inequality

$D_\alpha(p_{X'} || p_{Y'}) \leq R_1 + R_2$ by Theorem 9 and 28 from [1]

[1] van Erven, 2007, ‘Renyi Divergence and Kullback-Leibler Divergence’, IEEE transactions on Information Theory

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on $X$ or $Y$? Are they continuous, discrete or can they be anything? What about the noise? Do you assume any distribution there or are the Renyi divergence bounds the only assumption you make on the noise?

Comment: Thanks. All random variables are unimodal continuous distributions on $\mathbb{R^+}$, though there are no assumptions on the functional form.